# check if an object with a specific key value exists in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to check if an array of items contains an object with a specific key value, and if it does, just update the array of items with the new item object

```
[{name: example1, quantity: 2},{name: example2, quantity: 3},{name: example3, quantity: 5}]
```

so if for example I'm pushing an object with the same name of "example1", I want to check if it does exist in the array and if it does, just update it with the new object with the new quantity for example.

I tried to explain what I want as best as I can, please let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Do these objects only have `name` and `quantity` keys? If so, then you should just use a mapping, not an array of objects. If there's more keys in the objects, what would happen to those keys when you merge?

Comment: You should really add a) a before/after example of your array of objects (because, based on the answers, I'm not sure people understand what you want, and b) your own attempted solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a simple combination of **[`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** and **[`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** methods:

```
if (data.some(o => o.name == toPush.name)) {
  data.find(o => o.name == toPush.name).quantity = toPush.quantity;
}
```

Where `data` is your `array` and `toPush` is the `object` you are trying to update.

**Demo:**

```js
var data = [{
  name: "example1",
  quantity: 2
}, {
  name: "example2",
  quantity: 3
}, {
  name: "example3",
  quantity: 5
}];

let toPush = {
  name: "example2",
  quantity: 10
};

if (data.some(o => o.name == toPush.name)) {
  data.find(o => o.name == toPush.name).quantity = toPush.quantity;
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: I think this is the only answer that understands the question

Comment: @Andy Thank you, yes, he should check if the searched object exists and updates it.

Answer (score 3):

```
let arr1 = [{name: 'example1', quantity: 2},{name: 'example2', quantity: 3},{name: 'example3', quantity: 5}];
let obj1 = {name: 'example1', quantity: 5};
if(arr1.filter(item=> item.name === obj1.name).length==0){
  arr1.push(obj1);
}
else{
  arr1.filter(item=> item.name === obj1.name)[0].quantity = obj1.quantity;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.find()` for that update and pushing the unique objects. You can also use `existObj = obj;` so that all the updated properties of `obj` is set on the existing object and not just one property (as it is now with `quantity`). But if you need only the `quantity` property to get updated then use `existObj.quantity = obj.quantity;`

```js
let arr = [{name: 'example1', quantity: 2},{name: 'example2', quantity: 3},{name: 'example3', quantity: 5}];
let obj = {name: 'example1', quantity: 5};
var existObj = arr.find(({name}) => name === obj.name);
if(existObj){
  existObj = obj;
} else {
  arr.push(obj);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function:

```
const arr = [{name: 'example1', quantity: 2},{name: 'example2', quantity: 3},{name: 'example3', quantity: 5}]


var result = arr.some(e => e.hasOwnProperty('name') && e.hasOwnProperty('quantity'));

console.log("The array contains an object with a 'name' and 'quantity' property: " + result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use `Array.findIndex()` with this

```
let myArray = [{name: 'example1', quantity: 2},{name: 'example2', quantity: 3},{name: 'example3', quantity: 5}];
const newItem = { name: 'example1', quantity: 5 };
const indexOfItem = myArray.findIndex(item => item.name === item.name);

if(indexOfItem === -1) { // not existing
  myArray.push(newItem);
else {
  myArray[indexOfItem] = newItem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create "push" function and pass in the object you want to add/update. Function will take care if it needs to add / update arr by using "[find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)". Also, this will take care of all properties not just "quantity"

```js
var arr = [{name: 'example1', quantity: 2},{name: 'example2', quantity: 3},{name: 'example3', quantity: 5}]

function push(obj) {
  var data = arr.find(({name}) => name == obj.name) || (arr = arr.concat({})).slice(-1)[0];
  Object.assign(data, obj)
}

push({ name: 'example11', quantity: 100 })
console.log('example11 added', arr)

push({ name: 'example1', quantity: 100 })
console.log('example1 updated', arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which iterates through each object, and we can update existing array with using the index param.

Please see the below code.

```js
var data = [{name: "example1", quantity: 2},{name: "example2", quantity: 3},{name: "example3", quantity: 5}]

var object = {name: "example1", quantity: 14}

data.forEach((o,index) => {
  if(o.name === object.name){
    o.quantity = object.quantity
    return data[index] = o
  }else{
    data[index] = o
  }
})


console.log("updated data array =>", data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ObjectArray = [{name: 'example1', quantity: 2},{name: 'example2', quantity: 3},{name: 'example3', quantity: 5}]
    console.log(ObjectArray)
   var name = 'example2'
   var index = ObjectArray.findIndex(product => product.name == name);
   if(index>=0){
        console.log("Found and updated ObjectArray")
       ObjectArray.splice(index, 1, {name: 'example2', quantity: 8});
       console.log(ObjectArray)
   }
   else{
      console.log("not found")
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This code might be a good answer, but it would be better to avoid code-only answers and provide some explanation/context.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to match both object key & values, this will work.

```
let myArray = [{name: 'example1', quantity: 2},{name: 'example2', quantity: 3},{name: 'example3', quantity: 5}];
let newObj = { name: 'example1', quantity: 5 };

let myArrayJSON = JSON.stringify(myArray);
let newObjJSON = JSON.stringify(newObj);

if(myArrayJSON.indexOf(newObjJSON) === -1){
   myArray.push(newObj); 
}
```